# window.frames["printElem"].print() gives an empty preview

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

The angularjs directive I'm using

```
function printDiv() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                PrintElem(attrs.printDiv);
            });

            function PrintElem(elem) {
                PrintWithIframe($(elem).html());
            }

            function PrintWithIframe(data) {
                if ($('iframe#printf').size() == 0) {
                    $('html').append('<iframe id="printf" name="printf"></iframe>');     
                    var mywindow = window.frames["printf"];
                    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head><body>'
                        + data +
                        '</body></html>');

                    $(mywindow.document).ready(function() {
                        mywindow.print();

                        // $('iframe#printf').remove();
                    });
                } else {
                    window.frames["printf"].print();
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

If I remove the external css style link, the `mywindow.print()` works correctly. With these css style links, the first time I call `printDiv`, it always shows an empty preview and if I printed it out it's empty as well, but I can see the created `iframe` at the bottom of the page and it's not empty. If I call the function a second time, it will prints the correct preview. I googled around and found [someone](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/n37QjJcxyLg) suggested:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    mywindow.print();
}, 1000);
```

but I found the `print()` inside `setTimeout` was never called.
Any idea how to make print work at the first time? Thanks.

**Update**: After I replaced `document.write` with `document.body.innerHTML`, the preview isn't empty anymore, but the external css style never applied to the preview, although I can see the style in  `iframe` is correct. I tried this on both Firefox and Chrome.

```
$('html').append('<iframe id="printf" name="printf"></iframe>');

window.frames["printf"].document.body.innerHTML='<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' + $(attrs.printDiv).html();
$(window.frames["printf"].document).ready(function() {
    window.frames["printf"].window.focus();
    window.frames["printf"].window.print();

    // $('iframe#printf').remove();
});
```

Comment: frame should be inside body, `<link>` should be in <head>`

Comment: @charlietfl This's irrelevant to the problem here.

Comment: wasn't suggesting it was the fix you need, but should at least use valid html